# What is the standards-compliant way to advertise STARTTLS in ESMTP capabilities?

Tags: smtp, rfc

When I connect to an SMTP server, and issue an EHLO (ESMTP) greeting, some servers respond with:

```
250-STARTTLS
```

And other servers, respond with:

```
250 STARTTLS
```

Which is correct? [RFC 3207](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3207.txt) suggests that the hyphen is correct. But [RFC 2487](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2487) suggests there shouldn't be a hyphen. Are they both correct? of course, deployed code usually takes precedence over standards, but it would be nice to clarify this.

As a random sample, MessageLabs offer "250 STARTTLS" whereas Hotmail/Outlook offer "250-STARTTLS".

Comment: 2487 says right at the top *Obsoleted by: 3207* so I would go with whatever that says.

Comment: Thanks @AlexK, I think you're right. I'd just prefer it to be openly stated rather than "guess by the single example in the RFC".

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in [RFC 2821](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2821.txt). It specifies the following:

> Normally, the response to EHLO will be a multiline reply.  Each line
>      of the response contains a keyword and, optionally, one or more
>      parameters.  Following the normal syntax for multiline replies, these
>      keywords follow the code (250) and a hyphen for all but the last
>      line, and the code and a space for the last line

So RFC2487 has it without a space, because it's the last line of their sample SMTP session. RFC3207 has it with a hyphen, because it's not the last line (and this holds true for my Hotmail/Messagelabs example above).